# I am getting CORS error on NEST.JS LAMBDA PROXY application

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, nestjs, serverless-express

I am using Lambda proxy application which after deploying to AWS throws a cors error after request.

CORS is enabled on NEST.js application side

```
async function bootstrap(): Promise<Handler> {
  if (!cachedServer) {
    const expressApp = express();
    const nestApp = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(expressApp));

    const validationOptions = {
      validationError: { target: false },
    };
    nestApp.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe(validationOptions));
    const logger: Logger = new Logger(new PinoLogger(null));
    nestApp.useLogger(logger);
    nestApp.enableCors();
    nestApp.use(helmet());
    nestApp.useGlobalFilters(new ServiceExceptionFilter());
    await nestApp.init();

    cachedServer = serverlessExpress({ app: expressApp });
  }

  return cachedServer;
}

export const handler = async (event: any, context: Context, callback: any) => {
  if (event.path === '/swagger') {
    event.path = '/swagger/';
  }
  event.path = event.path.includes('swagger-ui') ? `/swagger${event.path}` : event.path;

  const server = await bootstrap();
  return server(event, context, callback);
};
```

here is the serverless.yml configuration part

```
functions:
  main:
    handler: src/lambda.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: /{any+}
          cors: true
```

Can someone explain what is the problem here ? why I am getting cors error from deployed AWS app ? I am using root user to run the app. It work fine locally. And btw if it will help I have health endpoint (GET) which works fine but POST and PATCH does not work.

Comment: how did you fix it? i have same problem

Comment: Hi @EnriqueArevalo, I met the same issue and fixed it by adding a middleware to add the cors headers to the response. You can check the full story here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77236997/769900

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

I met the same issue with Nestjs serverless express and the AWS API gateway. I can't remember from which version of nest js the problem occurred; the same code worked before.

Now, I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
    await app.init();

    app.enableCors({
        maxAge: 86400
    })


    const expressApp = app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance();
    return serverlessExpress({app: expressApp});
```

### Solution

So I have to use the following middleware to do the cors by hand:

```
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.header('access-control-allow-origin', '*');
        res.header('access-control-allow-credentials', 'true');
        next();
    })


    const expressApp = app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance();
    return serverlessExpress({app: expressApp});
```

### Analysis

Although it's not an ideal way of fixing issues, it'll just work. If something is wrong and it is problematic to find the root cause due to the complexity under the hood, then it's always possible to fix it by using raw solutions directly to the problem.

The problem is that the Cors headers are not returned, and the `app.enableCors()` failed to add them. I don't know what it is doing since there are too many layers to look through. Then, instead of troubleshooting all the stacks, it's much easier to manually write the raw middleware to add them to the response.

### Live example

Full commit for reference: https://github.com/Jeff-Tian/serverless-space/commit/6a9f8939b9518205dc7085adfcf3b202003d28cc#diff-49c3215f9e70066c7f189da517111db7d51b79e7cc5edca28e6e586d78ef9c08R11-R16

### Before the fix:

[image]

### After the fix:

[image]

### Some conclusions

After the fix, I'm 100% sure it has nothing to do with the AWS side. It's the nestjs with the serverless express problem.

Comment: Just change the order of calls & drop the options:   1) app.enableCors();   2) await app.init();   3) call the app...

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to set the following properties in response

1.'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': your origin value which you can get from request header

2. 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,